# Pass data.frame row-wise to function using purrr/furrr instead of apply

Tags: r, apply, purrr, furrr

**Question::**

What is the equivalent `purrr`/`furrr` function for `apply`, which takes a data-frame and row-wise feeds it to a function?

**Context::**

I have a data.frame of parameter combinations:

```
n=10

parameters <- data.frame(
lam = runif(n = n, min = .35, max = .5),
# cs = runif(n = n, min = 1.3, max = 2.5),
cs = rnorm(n = n, mean = 1.18, sd = 0.15),
af = runif(n = n, min = 1.5, max = 2.2)
)
```

I have a function that takes values from the parameters data.frame and produces a vector.

```
gradient_model <- function(parameters) {
lam <- parameters[1]
cs <- parameters[2]
af <- parameters[3]
x <- rep(0, 5)

    for (i in seq(1, 5)) {
        x[i + 1] <- x[i] + lam * (cs * af - x[i])
    }
  return(x %>% unlist())
}
```

Currently I'm using `apply` but can't find the equivalent `purrr` (and hence `furrr` for parallel) command

For every row of parameters run the recurrence function gradientModel and store the results in a data.frame

```
predictions <- apply(parameters, 1, gradient_model)
```

What is the equivalent purrr/furrr function?

Comment: Irrelevant to your question but why `x %>% unlist()` and not `unlist(x)`?

Comment: Good question! Maybe because I've been using dplyr a lot recently and it's a habit. Is there a performance penalty do you think?

Comment: Of course. You have to load a whole package just to use the pipe `%>%`. FYI there is a baseR pipe now `|>`

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! I thought that | > was a zoo thing. Good to know about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pmap*()` (and hence `future_pmap*()`) matches arguments by names, so you could do:

```
pmap_dfc(parameters, 
         function(lam, cs, af) {
             x <- rep(0, 5)
             
             for (i in seq(1, 5)) {
                 x[i + 1] <- x[i] + lam * (cs * af - x[i])
             }
             return(x)
         }) 

   ...1  ...2  ...3  ...4  ...5  ...6  ...7  ...8  ...9 ...10
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 0     0      0    0     0     0     0      0    0     0    
2 0.866 0.701  1.04 0.809 0.845 0.885 0.988  1.00 0.760 0.995
3 1.33  1.12   1.57 1.29  1.37  1.34  1.56   1.53 1.16  1.56 
4 1.57  1.37   1.84 1.59  1.70  1.57  1.89   1.81 1.36  1.88 
5 1.71  1.52   1.98 1.76  1.91  1.69  2.08   1.95 1.47  2.06 
6 1.78  1.61   2.05 1.86  2.03  1.76  2.19   2.03 1.53  2.16
```

Comment: It can't be that easy???! and at the same time, that hard!

Comment: I've just done a quick benchmark and it seems purrr is twice as slow as apply for n=1e5. Interesting, no?

Comment: I'm not really surprised, the `tidyverse` functions tend to be slightly slower :)

Comment: even using furrr::future_pmap is hardly different to purrr::pmap which is very strange